# Why is the external IP not returned from a UPnP GetExternalIPAddress query using powershell/COM?

Tags: powershell, com, upnp

I am trying to use powershell to query/control UPnP devices.

I researched and came up with using the UPnP.UPnPDeviceFinder object to get the list of upnp devices. 
Now as a first step to learn how to control a upnp device with powershell I want to get the external address of the router 
using the upnp WANConnectionDevice that my router contains.
The closest example I could find was for VBScript at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa381230(v=vs.85).aspx
Note the goal is to understand how to control upnp devices this way - there are better ways I know of to get the external IP.

get all the UPnP devices

```
$finder = New-Object -ComObject UPnP.UPnPDeviceFinder
$devices = $finder.FindByType("upnp:rootdevice", 0)
```

from my earlier experimenting I know the UPnP WANConnectionDevice is the grandchild of the router COM object

```
$router = $devices | where friendlyname -eq RT-N66U
$routerchild = $router | % {$_.Children}   # simple $router.Children syntax does not work, methods and properties are not available.
$routergrandchild = $routerchild | % {$_.Children}
```

this shows $routergrandchild is the WANConnectionDevice

```
$routergrandchild.FriendlyName
```

WANConnectionDevice

get the services object from this

```
$wanconnectservice = $routergrandchild | % {$_.services}
```

examine the invokeaction method

```
$wanconnectservice | gm -MemberType Method invokeaction
```

TypeName: System.__ComObject#{a295019c-dc65-47dd-90dc-7fe918a1ab44}

Name         MemberType Definition
----         ---------- ----------
InvokeAction Method     Variant InvokeAction (string, Variant, Variant)

From the get-member signature above and from my earlier experimenting I know the GetExternalIPAddress action has only 1 output arg
and no input args. So pass an empty array for input and for the 1 output arg pass a [ref]

```
$xip = @()
$wanconnectservice.InvokeAction('GetExternalIPAddress', @(), [ref]$xip)
```

The result of this is a request is sent to the router and it responds correctly with the externalip (confirmed by wireshark)
I would also expect an S_OK to be returned and have $xip contain the externalip string.
What I get is no response (no errors either) and $xip is unchanged.
I tried setting $xip = @('') and got the same result.

## Is my syntax wrong or are my expectations wrong? Maybe because the external IP has not changed I get nothing in $xip?

Note that

```
$wanconnectservice.QueryStateVariable('ExternalIPAddress')
```

does return the current address - but this is cached. There is no wireshark activity since ExternalIPAddress is an evented 
variable as noted in the documentation at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382244(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

Well, I am embarrassed to publish this but the solution is very simple:

```
$xip = **$null**
$wanconnectservice.InvokeAction('GetExternalIPAddress', @(), [ref]$xip)
$xip
```